# Connecting to SVN on a remote Windows server using Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I installed svn on my remote Windows 2008 server, the ip is 41.139.540.60 for example. Now, using Tortoise SVN on the server itself works using svn://localhost/. I can open the repo browser and so on. Now, how do I connect to that svn from my local PC? I tried svn://41.139.540.60, but it did not work, the message I got was the the server did not respond and thus connection failed. I cant ping the IP, so its a server issue I guess.

What else is needed to make it run?

Thanks :)

The guide I used was: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`svn://` protocol runs on `TCP port 3690`, so make sure your remote Windows Server 2008 allows clients to connect to this port.

An other option is to install Apache + mod_svn on your Windows 2008 server and connect to your repositories with `https://` rather than `svn://`

[Here is a useful guide for installing Apache and mod_svn](http://svn.spears.at/)

As you already installed SVN itself, you can start from section 2.3

Comment: No problem, glad it could help you. Please set this answer as your accepted answer if you like. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You may want to make sure that your Windows 2008 server has the proper firewall settings. Check the following ports:

svn://     port 3980

http://    port 80

ssh+svn:// port 22

depending on your configured protocol(s) for accessing the svn server, you should adapt the firewall ports on the Windows 2008.

Comment: Not working .... hm what else could be the problem? I cant even ping that IP from my local PC.

Comment: By default Windows Server 2008 firewall is configured with Windows Firewall running, and with File and Printer Sharing disabled.  This blocks ICMP Echo Request packets used by the PING command. 
Enable the File and Printer Sharing option in Windows Firewall Configuration Settings
Start > Control Panel > Network and Intranet
Under the Windows Firewall section heading, Click the Allow a program through Windows Firewall link In the programs and ports list, check the File and Printer Sharing option

Comment: Opening TCP port 3690 on the server was the solution, thanks.

Comment: @EOB: If this is the answer you are looking for, please mark it as the answer by clicking the √ mark next to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that guide only works for local users...

try this out: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html

or using svn+ssh http://csoft.net/docs/svn.html.en

Answer (score 0):

Check the video once

[config SVN server on localhost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eo3HrgbSXaE)

Steps to follow :

1. Download SVN server zip file, then extract it to a folder
2. Create reposistory
3. Start SVN server
4. Install SVN client (such as Tortoise SVN)
5. Browse SVN URL
6. Add folder, check out, and work on SVN
7. Add user to  commit file on SVN

Check the following ports:

```
svn:// port 3980
http:// port 80
ssh+svn:// port 22
```

Comment: Could you write down, what the steps in those video are, so others could benefit from your answer?