# Can I use a URL public IP to access a repository with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to use public IP to access an svn server using the Tortoise repository browser? I installed TortoiseSVN in our server, my project resides in our server, and I want to access this from home – is this possible? I successfully access by using the local ip of computer where my visual svn hosted in this case in our server machine. but I want to access this without connected in our network. I want to access this at home, to get files and update to my repository.

Something like this

`svn://svn.publicip:port/svn/myprojectfolder`

Is this possible? This is the first time I have used Subversion / Tortoise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends on svn server configuration.
Have you tried it? What was the error message?

Comment: I did not configure, I just installed the tortoise in the server, after that I create repository and import some test folder...when I am in my localmachine I tried to open the url browser in torotoise and point the url to my pulbicip,then after that it says cannot find host.

Comment: I don't know about "url browser", perhaps you meant "repository browser".
I guess that it is a networking issue. E.g. the domain name could not be resolved or host IP is not reachable from outside. I would try to `ping svn.publicip`

Comment: Does the same URL work on your server?

Comment: @szkj I can ping my server public ip `ping xxx.xx.xxx.xx` but if I ping like this `ping svn.xxx.xx.xxx.xx` Ping request could not find host ping svn.xxx.xx.xxx.xx. please check the name and try again.

Comment: @PJTraill yes I tried to execute in the cmd in our server like this svn ls https://nameofourserver.com:8443/svn/mytest-rep/

Comment: Could a firewall be blocking port 8443? See [checking a port is open on a windows server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-to-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-a-windows-server) for some tips. I feel sure the name of the host is not going to be `svn.xxx.xx.xxx.xx`!

Comment: [PsPing from sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx) also sounds worth a look.

Comment: It sounds to me a bit as though you have only created a repository with Tortoise, as described in [the Tortoise manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup.html), but not actually started a server. If so, you will not be able to access it via the network (other than on a share, which is usually [a bad idea](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share)) – Tortoise is a _client_, not a _server_. See [the Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.html) for how to set up a server.

Comment: @PJTraill I think the port is block..yes I switch to visual svn server,but then the porst is block. I have no access even I open the port in firewall

Comment: This one seems to be a similar problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711571/connecting-to-svn-on-a-remote-windows-server-using-tortoise-svn).
It says that `svn://` protocol runs on `TCP port 3690` (by default). Try to open it as well.

Comment: @jemz: Could you add to your question the command you use to start the server?